# How to work with migrations when using multiple databases with TypeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, orm, typeorm

I'm building a multi-tenant solution where each tenant will have their own database. I'm using TypeORM for managing the database related stuff and right now I'm stuck with handling migrations when I have multiple databases. The common way for generating a migration is to specify the path to the datasource file, which will hold one datasource. As far as I understand, even if I would manually create 5 different datasources in that file, I would still have to migrate them one by one?

But the real issue is when there's 50+ databases, now I would need to fetch the database settings dynamically and generate new migrations for all of them. (The databases will all have the same structure). Am I approaching this completely wrong or how would this be solved? If not possible with TypeORM, how is this solved in other applications with the same scenario?

Thanks in advance

So far I've only tried manually or "the standard" way of generating migrations. The other solution I've found is to build by own migration script...

Comment: Hi… did you find a solution to this? I am searching for the same answers.

Comment: @Krishna I didn’t find a straight forward solution. But I think the way to do it is you have a db-table holding all db-connection info. Then you build a custom script that loops through all db-connections and runs the migrations on each of them. Haven’t done it myself yet, so not completely sure.